# Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead (webpack)?

Tags: webpack

Хочу собрать less файлы. Вот код конфига.

```
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), // корень контекст

    // Точки входа
    entry: {
        index: './index'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader' , 'less-loader']
                })
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'style.css',
            allChunks: true
        })
    ],

}
```

А пишет ошибку

```
C:\inetpub\my_code\projects\javascript\webpack\webpack-test-13>webpack
(node:23372) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
(node:23372) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.apply is deprecated. Call apply on the plugin directly instead
C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824
                throw new Error(
                ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead
    at Chunk.get (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824:9)
    at C:\inetpub\my_code\projects\javascript\webpack\webpack-test-13\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\inetpub\my_code\projects\javascript\webpack\webpack-test-13\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
    at Compilation.seal (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1213:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:547:17)
    at _err0 (eval at create (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12), <anonymous>:11:1)
    at _addModuleChain (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1064:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\Users\дима\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:980:9)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Как нужно исправить код, чтобы решить эту задачу?

Comment: почему вы по каждой проблеме создаете вопрос здесь? в интернете же есть куча решений данной проблемы (`npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next`)

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Быстро решение не нашел поэтому и задал вопрос тут.